# What does this sed command mean?

Tags: shell-script, sed

What does this mean in a shell script?

```
| sed 's/ /':'/' | sed 's/ /-/' > file.list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the context is

```
some-command | sed 's/ /':'/' | sed 's/ /-/' > file.list
```

Let's break it apart piece by piece.  Suppose for example that `some-command` is `echo 'test of the command'`.

Then `sed 's/ /':'/'` replaces the first space by `:`.

`test of the command` → `test:of the command`

After that, `sed 's/ /-/'` replaces the new first space by `-`

`test:of the command` → `test:of-the command`

This transformation is applied on each line of the output of `some-command`.

---

As mentioned by @Philippos in the comments, it is unclear why `:` is unquoted here.  It would be better as

```
some-command | sed 's/ /:/' | sed 's/ /-/' > file.list
```

But `sed` is not restricted to a single replacement per instance.  So even better is

```
some-command | sed 's/ /:/; s/ /-/' > file.list
```

Comment: You could add that there is no obvious reason why the `:` is outside the quoting or why this is double-piped instead of `sed 's/ /:/;s/ /-/'`